# How to transform JSONObject to Map<String, Object>?

Tags: arrays, json, types, format, transformation

I have a json like this stored on JSONObject:

```
{
"players":
 {
    "key": "03a2452c-9d6b-47f5-9616-9a6833312762",
    "value": {
              "uuid": "2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3",
              "name": "Artur",
              "elo": 2000,
              "gamesPlayed": 0,
              "email": "arti123@mail"
              }
  },
  {
    "key": "8526db7c-6930-45bf-9ae1-fb93e97ff4ba",
    "value": {
             "uuid": "1bb43d73-3f94-40fc-a680-99f4a9304001",
             "name": "Kamil",
             "elo": 2000,
             "gamesPlayed": 0,
             "email": "kamil22@mail"
             }
 }
 "games:" ....

}
```

I want to store "players:" data in Map<String, Object>, where String is "key" value and Object has "value" data in it. Could you help me with any ideas of how to implement this transformation?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"players\":[{\"key\":\"03a2452c-9d6b-47f5-9616-9a6833312762\",\"value\":{\"uuid\":\"2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3\",\"name\":\"Artur\",\"elo\":2000,\"gamesPlayed\":0,\"email\":\"arti123@mail\"}},{\"key\":\"8526db7c-6930-45bf-9ae1-fb93e97ff4ba\",\"value\":{\"uuid\":\"1bb43d73-3f94-40fc-a680-99f4a9304001\",\"name\":\"Kamil\",\"elo\":2000,\"gamesPlayed\":0,\"email\":\"kamil22@mail\"}}]}";
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray players = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("players");
        System.out.println(players);
    }

}
```